# jquery zoom and carousel shopping module bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zooming, carousel

I have modified a jquery zoom and carousel module for a shopping site that works wonderfully (kind of) except that the carousel works properly if the list items are 6 or more. If there are 5 items in the carousel, then two issues occur:

1. The left and right scroll button stop working -> one cannot see the 6th item.
2. The whole list of carousel item are not lined up properly.  They all dip below the scrolling line.

If there are 4 items in the list then we don't expect the left and right scroll to work but they are still not lined up properly.

I just cannot figure out what is wrong.  I have created the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tapioca/2oedcvrf/) with 7 items.  If you remove one of the items under  `<ul class=list-h> <li>...`  You will see the problem.  Any help is appreciated. If you can get this to work properly, I am sure many people will benefit from this. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Edit this line in your script code

```
if(s.deriction=="left"||s.deriction=="right"){
    var width=subObject.length*subObject.eq(0).outerWidth();
    object.css({width:width+"px",overflow:"hidden"});
    var step=s.step*subObject.eq(0).outerWidth();
};
```

become:

```
if(s.deriction=="left"||s.deriction=="right"){
    var width=subObject.length*subObject.eq(0).outerWidth();
    object.css({width:width+"px",overflow:"hidden",marginLeft:-30,marginTop:0});
    var step=s.step*subObject.eq(0).outerWidth();
};
```

I have tried in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2oedcvrf/5/) and it works fine with 5 items.

I hope it can help you, at least to narrow down where to look.

Comment: Thank you.  At least it solves the level issue.  It works now with the 350 width because the 5 items fits perfectly within the scroll bars.  However, if the width is not 350 and the last item, say the 5th photo is only shown half way, the scroll will still not work.